# vhistory in report resulting in compiling error

Tags: errors, luatex, compiling, changes

I'm trying to add a history in a report file of mine.  No matter how I try to implement the vhistory package into the file it runs several compiling errors, usually starting with a

> Error Line 6 ! Undefined control sequence.\endlongtable ...@echunk \global \setbox \LT@gbox\hbox {\unhbox \LT@gbox }... \end {longtable}

> Error Line 6 ! Missing number, treated as zero.\hbox \end {longtable}

Also some errors more.  This also happens if I only use the minimum commands possible, like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{ngerman, hyperref}
\usepackage{vhistory}

\begin{document}
    Some Text

    \begin{versionhistory}
        \vhEntry{1.0}{22.01.04}{JPW|KW}{Erstellung}
        \vhEntry{1.1}{23.01.04}{DP|JPW}{Fehlerkorrektur}
        \vhEntry{1.2}{03.02.04}{DP|JPW}{\"Uberarbeitung nach Review}
    \end{versionhistory}
\end{document}
```

basically an extract from the example of the package documentation.  Which btw. does also not compile in my system with texmaker.  Same kind of errors.  So I'm kind of lost why this is happening.
I'm compiling with Lualatex but tried also with latex alone.  Did not differ at all.
I appreciate any help here!

Thanks,
Nana

Comment: Welcome To TeX StackExchange! On my up-to-date TeXLive 2021 your document compiles successfully with both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, so it seems to be system specific. Is your system up-to-date? Which TeX distribution do you use (TeX Live? MikTeX? MacTeX?)

Comment: you have wrapped the error message which makes it hard to tell which command is undefined. I assume it is `\LT@gbox`  which was added in the 2020 longtable release, but hard to guess how you got code that is using that but not defining it. Can you show your full log from the file posted.

Comment: unrelated but you should not use the ngerman package, that is really outdated. Use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead.

Comment: Woha, that was going quickly.  Thanks for reading this ;-)
I'm using MikTex, CurrentVersion: 21.2
I will try to update shortly.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is painful now.

An update of Miktex did the trick and it compiles without error.  Sorry for this!  mea culpa...